# Training NER using spacy on Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, spacy

I am trying to train custom entities using spacy on google colab.
But when I try to configure the spacy config file by using

```
!python3 -m spacy debug data base_config.cfg

✘ Unknown command: debug
Available: download, link, info, train, pretrain, debug-data, evaluate, convert,
package, init-model, profile, validate

!python3 -m spacy init fill-config base_config.cfg config_spacy_bert.cfg 

✘ Unknown command: init
Available: download, link, info, train, pretrain, debug-data, evaluate, convert,
package, init-model, profile, validate
```

I couldn't find the reason for this. Its working in my local machine.

Comment: here i tried custom ner recognition using spacy in colab : https://github.com/mobassir94/NLP-and-Bangla-NLP/blob/master/Training_NER_for_recognizing_drugs!.ipynb


!pip3 install spacy
!python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
i used these commands and for my custom entities training using spacy i didn't use the command you are using,is it necessary?looking forward to learn from you,thanks

Comment: I can see that you worked with spacy (2.2.4). I am working with spacy3. There are several changes in spacy 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to upgrade `spacy` in colab first. To do this cleanly:

```
!python -m pip uninstall -y spacy
!python -m pip install -U spacy
```

Check the version with:

```
!python -m spacy info
```

Comment: I knew i have to work with spacy3 and i dint check the version of spacy in colab. My mistake. Thanks for pointing me this :)